# How do I fix an unfounded 'Use of undeclared type' error in Xcode 8 / Swift 3?

Tags: xcode, swift3

The other day, after I did a full text search for a string in Xcode, Xcode started to report 'Use of undeclared type' for two of my classes.

One class I had not touched in months, the other is a fundamental class, but I know they both exist and everything is named correctly.

If I build, it will succeed, but I will still get a little red error warnings all over my code as if it failed every where one of the classes in question are used, and they will not go away even if I perform a clean build.

However, if I quit Xcode, reopen, and rebuild the problem might go away for a little bit.  But it will usually return I make any changes to code anywhere.

Has anyone else had this problem, and how do I make it stop?

Thanks

Stan

Comment: Check the Target membership of the class files that Xcode says are undeclared.

Comment: Do a clean build, quit Xcode, purge the DerivedData folder, and restart Xcode.

Comment: I had this persistent problem with a big monolithic project. I split the project in 12 dynamic frameworks and the problem disappeared. A bug in Xcode I guess. A legit reason could be that the frameworks containing the offending classes are not available until the linking phase.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Taverne'S comment about checking the Target membership, seemed to be the winner.

For some reason is the file's association with one of the Tests had become unchecked and that was causing the problem.